# "Decode" messages sent through skype mobile

Tags: skype, decoding

I was in a group chat with my friends on skype, and they were sending messages such as:

It shows up as just a bunch of squares... how can I decode stuff like this? All my friends were on their iPods, so that might be part of it...

I've tried changing the character set and font, but no luck...

Comment: Were they using Emoji? What type of keyboard was set up?

Comment: I have no idea. They refuse to tell me >_>

Comment: They aren't very tech savvy, so I would assume they only had access to whatever is available by default.

Comment: What OS are you using? I've found that in many cases Windows simply *does not support codepoints in latest Unicode versions*, which Linux [displays fine](http://i.imgur.com/HWs70.png) -- even though the same font and program is in use... In particular, your example is a row of [U+1F4A9 "Pile of poo"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm) characters, part of Unicode 6.0.

Comment: I've never said this before, but a pile of poo seems like the best answer here.